# Difference between HashMap and Map in Java..?

Tags: java, hashmap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java - HashMap vs Map objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348199/java-hashmap-vs-map-objects)

I want to know the difference between `HashMap` and `Map` in java..??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348199/java-hashmap-vs-map-objects

Comment: Try compiling this snippet: `new HashMap<String, String>(); new Map<String, String>();`

Answer (score 80):

`Map` is an interface, i.e. an abstract "thing" that defines how something can be used. `HashMap` is an implementation of that interface.

Answer (score 34):

`Map<K,V>` is an interface,
`HashMap<K,V>` is a class that implements `Map`.

you can do

```
Map<Key,Value> map = new HashMap<Key,Value>();
```

Here you have a link to the documentation of each one:
[Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

Answer (score 7):

`Map` is an interface; `HashMap` is a particular implementation of that interface.

HashMap uses a collection of hashed key values to do its lookup.  TreeMap will use a red-black tree as its underlying data store.

Answer (score 5):

`Map` is an interface in Java. And `HashMap` is an implementation of that interface (i.e. provides all of the methods specified in the interface).

Answer (score 3):

`HashMap` is an implementation of `Map`. [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) is just an interface for any type of map.