# Creating objects of Hashmap and assigning it to map reference. Why?

Tags: java

Why we use,

Map abc = new HashMap(20);

instead of

HashMap abc = new HashMap(20);

please help me to find out the differnce between these two.

would be grateful for help.

Comment: This is somewhat a `code design pattern` in `Java` that you use a `super` type reference whenever possible. here is the same case

Comment: You should avoid using raw types and use the generic type `HashMap<T,S>` or `Map<T,S>` as much as possible, it will be both more readable and both type safe.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - HashMap vs Map objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348199/java-hashmap-vs-map-objects)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first case, the `abc` variable is of type `HashMap`, which is an implementation of the `Map` interface. If you change your mind later and want to use a `TreeMap` for instance, you will have to change many references to `HashMap` in your code, and is is possible you used peculiarities of `HashMap` where the generic `Map` operations are enough.

If you use the `Map` interface as type for you variable, you can change the implementation easily.
It is important when you design classes for reuse. If you have a method that takes a `Map` as argument, any `Map` implementation will be usable to call your method. Thus, the caller will be free to use the most suitable implementation.

Comment: You might want to check this answer too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348199/java-hashmap-vs-map-objects

Comment: Is there any other purpose? It is in general that, we can change the reference whenever we required.

Comment: I Agree. The question should be "why should I use a `HashMap` and not a `Map`". You should always look for using the highest possible type in the object hirerchy, and have a good reason why not to go one level upper in the hirerchy, not the other way around.