# Different Ways of Creating HashMaps

Tags: java, hashmap

I've been learning about HashMaps recently but I have one question that I can't seem to get a clear answer on. The main difference between -

```
HashMap hash1 = new HashMap();
```

vs

```
HashMap<,>hash1 = new HashMap <,> (); //Filled in with whatever Key and Value you want.
```

I thought when you define a HashMap it requires the Key and Value. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Also, it's good habit to declare the variable a Map - take a quick look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348199/java-hashmap-vs-map-objects) for more info.

Comment: Java, and thank you for the post.

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't mark any of the answers as accepted answer?

Answer (score 21):

Those are the options you have:

J2SE <5.0 style:

```
 Map map = new HashMap();
```

J2SE 5.0+ style (use of [generics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java)):

```
 Map<KeyType, ValueType> map = new HashMap<KeyType, ValueType>();
```

[Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) style (shorter and more flexible):

```
 Map<KeyType, ValueType> map = Maps.newHashMap();
```

Answer (score 11):

You should take a look on [Java generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/), if you don't specify the types of the HashMap, both key and value will be `Object` type.

So, if you want a HashMap with `Integer` keys and `String` values for instance:

```
    HashMap<Integer, String> hashMap= new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

Comment: you're welcome @StaticGamedude , could you please consider mark it as the answer? That check mark under the helpful votes :)

Answer (score 3):

Specifying the `key` and the `value` types allows for greater type-safety by enabling compile-time typing enforcement.

This makes it easier to write code that doesn't accidentally mix up the key and value types, and reduces the amount of casts that you must explicitly declare in the code.

However, it is important to be aware the these type-checks are compile-time only, i.e. once the application is running, the JVM will allow you to use any types for the keys and values.

Comment: +1 for good explanation about compile-time and run-time differences.

Answer (score 1):

**-** `Generics` can be implied to classes, interfaces, methods, variables etc..  but the **most important reason** for which its used is making the `Collection` **more type safe**.

**-** `Generics` make sure that **only specific type of object enters and comes out** of the `Collections`.

**-** Moreover its worth mentioning that there is a process known as `Erasure`,

-> `Erasure` is a process where the `type parameters` and `type arguments` are **removed from the generic classes and interfaces by the compiler**, making it **back compatible** with the codes that where written **without** Generics.

So,

`HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();`

becomes of `Raw type`,

`HashMap map = new HashMap();`