# How can I call a user defined method which has hashmap as an argument?

Tags: java, collections

This is my code...

```
public class HashTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       HashTest ht = new HashTest();
       ht.test(?,"abc");

    }

    public void test(HashMap<String, String> hm, String country) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("No. of Input : ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Values : ");
        String capital = "";
        int city;
        for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++) {
            country = sc.next();
            capital = sc.next();
            hm.put(country, capital);

        if (hm.containsValue(country)) {
            System.out.println("Result : " +hm.get(capital));
        }
    }
```

Now inside the main method when calling the test method, then what will be the actual parameter in place of `?`?

Comment: you might want to add a `java` tag for this

Comment: Just create a `new HashMap<String, String>()` and pass it?

Comment: Hi Bergi,Can you show me a sample of code, how to call it exactly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are executing main just for testing, you could do:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   HashTest ht = new HashTest();
   HashMap hm=new HashMap<String, String>(); 
   ht.test(hm,"abc");

}
```

If someone is using this class from "outside". They would do

```
//some user code
HashTest ht= new HashTest();
HashMap hm=new HashMap<String, String>();
ht.test(hm,"abc");
//more user code
```

Which is practically the same.

There are some more ways to create and initialize a HashMap. Check [Different Ways of Creating HashMaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13144685/different-ways-of-creating-hashmaps)

Comment: No problem @DeepayanPal  Make sure to label this as accepted answer if that's the case.