# whats the different between when i create object from map and hashmap

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java - HashMap vs Map objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348199/java-hashmap-vs-map-objects)

whats the different between

```
private Map<String, Integer> drawableMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

and

```
private HashMap<String, Integer> drawableMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Comment: See [Type List vs type ArrayList in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279030/type-list-vs-type-arraylist-in-java)

Comment: look up "programming to interface"

Comment: You can see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852831/polymorphism-why-use-list-list-new-arraylist-instead-of-arraylist-list-n

Answer (score 1):

The type of the variable at the left-hand side of your assignment expression has nothing to do with object creation; therefore in both cases you are creating the **exact same object**. Since in Java you can only store a **reference** to an object into a variable, the type of that variable constrains the types of object the variable can refer to. In the first case it can refer to any object that implements `Map`; in the second, only `HashMap` objects are acceptable.

The other consequence is that in the first case you can only call methods of `HashMap` that are declared in the `Map` interface, whereas in the second case you can call any additional methods specific to the `HashMap` implementation.

In most real-world cases you will prefer the first case since you almost never need implementation-specific methods. The same rule goes for the complete Collections Framework.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, you can later assign `drawableMap` to other implementations of `Map` (e.g. `LinkedHashMap`). In the second example, you cannot - you are confined to `HashMap`s (and any of its subclasses). Generally, the first approach would be preferred over the second as it would provide greater flexibility down the road.

Ultimately, the first statement creates a variable of *type* `Map` that is an instance of `HashMap`. The second creates a variable of *type* `HashMap` that is also an instance of `HashMap`.