# Converting ConcurrentHashMap to HashMap

Tags: java

Is it possible to convert `ConcurrentHashMap` to `HashMap` in java ?

This is my sample program where i was converting from `ConcurrentHashMap` to `HashMap` but i was getting the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
>   java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap
>   at com.Hi.main(Hi.java:18)

My code:

```
package com;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class Hi {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Map<String, String> conpage = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();

        conpage.put("1", "A");
        conpage.put("2", "B");
        conpage.put("3", "C");

        HashMap hm = (HashMap) conpage;

        System.out.println(hm.get("1"));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 13):

```
Map<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>(conpage);
```

A `ConcurrentMap` (like `ConcurrentHashMap`) has no relationship with any `AbstractMap`, such has `HashMap`, so the solution is to create a new `HashMap` adding all values from `ConcurrentHashMap` during object creation.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

A [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) is not a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) , so you cannot perform this cast.  Treat them as [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) regardless of implementation.

Nevertheless , you can use [Map#putAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll(java.util.Map)) .

**Suggested Reading:**

1. [Java - HashMap vs Map objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348199/java-hashmap-vs-map-objects?lq=1)
2. [What does it mean to “program to an interface”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

Answer (score 3):

Use [putAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll%28java.util.Map%29) method istead of type casting like this:

```
HashMap hm=new HashMap<String, String>();
hm.putAll(conpage);
```

Answer (score 2):

ConcurrentHashMap and HashMap are siblings and not Parent-Child related. Hence the cast fails.

Answer (score 2):

To be more explicit in the explanation of the previous comments: consider you have three classes :

```
class Position {
}

class One extends Position {
  String gold = "the best";
}

class Two extends Position {
  String silver = "just wait next year!";
}
```

You cannot do the following cast (note that a cast is not a conversion: it's only a redeclaration of the type)

```
void showPosition() {
  Position one = new One(); // this is regular since One extends Position
  Two two = (Two)one; // this is impossible because one is not a two
}
```

If ever this cast was possible, how would you like the compiler to handle the following promblem? : there is no field called silver in one: so calling

```
((Two)one).silver
```

is impossible: returning null would be unsafe, since you wouldn't understand what's happening : since you know that the field 'silver' is initialized to the value "just wait next year!"

Java being a safe language, it doesn't allow this type of errors (actually it's a help from Java that it throws the exception since you think the type is something else that is it is).

The behvior you expect is rather a behavior proper to scripts.

Answer (score 1):

A ConcurrentHashMap is still a Map. So you can create a new TreeMap like this:

```
ConcurrentHashMap myMap;
...
TreeMap myTreeMap = new TreeMap( myMap );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do so in the following way -

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(conpage);
```

[JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#HashMap%28java.util.Map%29).

Typically each concrete type in the Java Collection API (like HashMap, ArrayList etc.) has a constructor which takes a reference of its parent (like Map, List) and constructs a new object from it.

About the exception you are getting, it's because `ConcurrentHashMap` is not a subtype/supertype of `HashMap`, thus you are getting a `ClassCastException`. However, this would have worked fine -

```
Map<String, String> hm = (Map<String, String> ) conpage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually There is no inheritance relation between HashMap and ConcurrentHashMap that's why while casting the concurrenthashmap object to hashmap its giving the ClassCastException.