# Map and HashMap

Tags: java

What are the difference? Please see below.

```
HashMap<Integer, String> hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

and

```
Map<Integer, String> hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, String();
```

Are they interchangeable ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348199/java-hashmap-vs-map-objects

Answer (score 5):

A `Map<K, V>` is an *interface*, a `HashMap<K, V>` is a *class* implementing the interface.

I always prefer the second option, unless you specifically want the charasterics of a `HashMap<K, V>`.

With the latter approach it is possible to switch out the `HashMap<K, V>` for another implementation of the `Map<K, V>` easily.

#### Another example of coding against interfaces

Take the `List<E>` vs `ArrayList<E>` approach as other example:

- If you define it as `ArrayList<E> list = new ArrayList<>()`, then you cannot easily change it to a `LinkedList<>()`, as `ArrayList<E> list = new LinkedList<>()` does not compile.
- However if you declare it as `List<E> list = new ArrayList<>()`, then you can switch it out to a `LinkedList<>()` at any time.

#### An example of coding against interfaces in methods

Let's say you have a method that accepts a `List<E>`, what should you do then?

1. Make it as `void method(ArrayList<E> list)`;
2. Or make it as `void method(List<E> list)`

Now you generally always want it to be a `List<E>`, when you *do not* care about the type of the list, and you only care about the operations available in the `List<E>` interface.

However there are cases where you possibly do want to force constant access times, it that case it could very well make sense to only let your method accept `ArrayList<E>`, because that implementation provided constant access times.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in the variable `hashMap`. If you create it like this:

```
HashMap hashMap = new HashMap();
```

you will be able to use all of `HashMap`'s methods.

If you create it like this:

```
Map hashMap = new HashMap();
```

then you will be restricted to the methods of the `Map` interface.

The difference is that `HashMap` is an implementation of the `Map` interface. You can say that in most cases it is better to use the `Map` interface because generally you don't need to know about the details of the implementation **and** this way you can swap implementations in no time.

This comes from the general guideline of *[program to interfaces not implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)*.

Just a note:

You should use **generics** where applicable.

Comment: @Whomever downvoted: care to explain?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i see from the javadoc, HashMap does not add any new methods, so for these two classes there is no difference.

On general principle, it's better to use interfaces rather than classes whenever possible.