# Trying to understand different ways of declaring an object in Java?

Tags: java

I am trying to understand what is the difference between the below 2 lines of code.

I know for a reason that one is of the reference type `List` and the other of the reference type `ArrayList`. But does it really matter or is it just 2 different ways of doing the same thing ?

Its not only with these classes/interface but with others as well. I believe it is a Polymorphism feature of an object taking different forms is that correct ?

```
List a1 = new ArrayList();
ArrayList a1 = new ArrayList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`List a1` is an interface meaning that for example it can reference a `LinkedList` as well (doesn't restrict the implementation to `ArrayList`).

While `ArrayList a1` can be  only assigned `ArrayList` instances, which is a restriction you don't wish to have sometimes.

It is usually considered better approach to use interfaces (`List`, `Map` etc.) instead of concrete types especially if you expose methods to external apps, therefore you don't enforce implementation details. You just expect the variable `a1` to behave as a `List`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't declare objects, you declare *variables* (and members).

The difference in the *interface* you have to the object. In the first case, the interface is `List`, whereas in the second it's `ArrayList`. The underlying object is the same, but you have different access to it. In theory, `ArrayList` could have methods that `List` doesn't have (although in practice I don't think it does).

The advantage to using `List` is that you can change the underlying object to be a different kind of list (by changing what kind you create) without breaking your contract with any code that's using it. If you declare it as `ArrayList`, you have to change your contract if you want to change the underlying implementation.

Disclosure: This is an adapted form of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1348228/157247) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1348199/157247). It's basically the same question, but you probably wouldn't find it when looking with the terms you were using. :-)

Comment: You self-plagiator! :)

Answer (score 0):

List is an interface, ArrayList implements that interface.

```
List a1 = new ArrayList();
```

a1 will be a List variable that contains an instance of the object ArrayList, the cast of the new ArrayList to List will be done implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

It does have to do with inheritance/polymorphism. Think of it as similar to:

```
Animal dog1 = new Dog();
Dog dog2 = new Dog();
```

Both will let you perhaps .eat(), but only dog2 can .bark()