# Why are the types different in Java variable declarations?

Tags: java

What is the purpose of specifying different types on the left and the right side in Java variable declarations?

For example, code like this is standard:

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
```

Why don't:

```
ArrayList<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
```

or

```
Object l = new ArrayList<>(); // Silly example but shows two extremes
```

Comment: in short: abstraction

Comment: @RaulRene the question is not about the generics here...

Comment: we can always use `ArrayList<String> l = new ArrayList<>();` there is nothing wrong. It only depends on how you want to use it. Also `Object l = new ArrayList<>(); ` is also correct depending on the use.

Comment: Also duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348199/java-hashmap-vs-map-objects

Comment: I feel could you clarify what you exactly want to ask?\

Comment: @Blip as a rule of thumb, variable types should be the most general type possible as (among other things) doing so reduces coupling.  With `List`s this means your declaration should be `List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>()` (or better `Collection<String>` strings = new ArrayList<>()`) - the T.J. Crowder's answer in the duplicate explains this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- This `List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();` allows you to instantiate
  all types of `List`, be it `ArrayList` or `LInkedList`of `String`. You can use all methods of `List`
- `ArrayList<String> l = new ArrayList<>();` you can only instantiate `ArrayList` of `String`.
- `Object l = new ArrayList<>();` you cannot use `List` methods.

Comment: @maba horrible mistake, my apologies thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

When you do this, you `cannot use` list operations like `add()`, `remove()`, `addAll()`, etc.

```
Object l = new ArrayList<>();
```

Here, you are loosing the flexibility of polymorphism:

```
ArrayList<String> l = new ArrayList<>();// later you could not re-initialize
l = new LinkedList<String>();//compile time error
```

Comment: re-initialization like that could cause side-effects and more. IMHO it is bad practice to do things like that.

Comment: @B.Kemmer that's true but not the point. Instead of re-initialization you should think of changing the implementation to a LinkedList. That would probably require more code changes if you declared as ArrayList than as the List interface.

Comment: @Adriaan Koster The point is that List<String> does prevent a lot of trouble. For example it's easier to add unit tests to your code etc. Check this post for further informations http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073649/core-java/why-extends-is-evil.html

Comment: @B.Kemmer I already got the point. You commented on re-initialization being bad practice which is not relevant to the discussion.