# java: difference between map and hash table

Tags: java, dictionary

I don't understand this code `Map<E, Integer> d = new HashTable<E, Integer>(list.size());` : we create a new object but is it a map or a hashtable? what is the difference between the both of them? I thought that a map is just a way to put 2 element together like a key and its value (for exemple {3; Detroit})

Comment: `Map` is an interface; `Hashtable` is an implementation of this interface (and so is `HashMap` which you should use instead)

Comment: Are you asking what is the difference between an interface and an implementing class?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348199/java-hashmap-vs-map-objects

Comment: yes, what is a difference between  an interface and an implementing class?

Comment: @christinejakotte I think you might benefit from reading the following.  The sub-links "What is Inheritance" and "What is an Interface" would be particularly helpful, I think.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/

Answer (score 3):

> is it a map or a hashtable?

Yes.

The static, compile time type of the reference is `Map`.  As others have already pointed out, it's an interface.  You can call all the methods on the `Map` interface and know that they'll obey the contract and behave as describe.

The dynamic, run time type of the object reference refers to is `Hashtable`.  It implements all the methods in the `Map` interface in its own way.

The key idea is that the compile time type of a reference is separate from the run time type of the object on the heap that it points to.

`Hashtable` is a JDK 1.0 class that sticks around for compatibility reasons.  It's been retrofitted to implement the `Map` interface, which was introduced later.  You'd be well advised to choose another implementation, such as `HashMap`, depending on your requirements.

The last part of `Hashtable` contains the reason why it should not be used:

> As of the Java 2 platform v1.2, this class was retrofitted to implement the `Map` interface, making it a member of the Java Collections Framework. Unlike the new collection implementations, `Hashtable` is synchronized. If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use `HashMap` in place of `Hashtable`. If a thread-safe highly-concurrent implementation is desired, then it is recommended to use `ConcurrentHashMap` in place of `Hashtable`.

This means that it is less efficient than `HashMap` for single-thread models and less efficient than `ConcurrentHashMap` for multi-threaded models.

Understanding how compile and run time types differ is crucial to understanding how object oriented polymorphism works.  This is true for all OO languages: C++, Java, .NET, Python, etc.

Answer (score 2):

`Map` is an interface. `Hashtable` is one of the classes that implements the `Map` interface.

See the [Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) for the `Map` interface. Specifically the section that says all known implementing classes.

Any class that implements a Map provides a `key->value` data-structure. A `Map` being an interface defines the contract that all implementing classes must adhere to. By itself, a `Map` cannot be instantiated.

Note that while `Hashtable` should ideally have been named as `HashTable` following the java naming conventions, this is is a pre-historic class in Java which exists even before the standard java naming conventions came into existence. Therefore, it is still called `Hashtable` and not `HashTable` as wrongly mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 1):

[`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) is an *interface*. `HashTable` is one *implementation*  of that interface. There are several others, such as `HashMap`, `SortedMap`, etc. The interface defines the programming API; the implementation defines *how* that API is implemented. Different implementations may have different runtime performance characteristics.

With regard to interfaces vs. implementations, you may find [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1348228/157247) to [*Java - HashMap vs Map objects*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348199/java-hashmap-vs-map-objects) here helpful.