# Java static variables not being initialised when deserialising xml using jackson

Tags: java, jackson-dataformat-xml

I got an issue when trying to deserialise xml using jackson.

I am using the following function to deserialise my xml from the file.

The Xml file is as-:

https://github.com/Eno-Gerguri/Pygame-Studio/blob/master/Settings/defaultSettings.xml

Here is the function I'm using to deserialise the object:

```
    public Settings deserializeSettings(File settingsFile) {
        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        String xml = null;
        Settings settings = null;
        
        try {
            xml = inputStreamToString(new FileInputStream(settingsFile));
            
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            
        }
        try {
            settings = xmlMapper.readValue(xml, Settings.class);
            
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            
        }
        
        return settings;
    }
    
    private String inputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
```

The Settings object I'm using that I am deserialising into:-

https://github.com/Eno-Gerguri/Pygame-Studio/blob/master/src/com/pygame_studio/settings/Settings.java

The sub-class that the Settings object uses:

https://github.com/Eno-Gerguri/Pygame-Studio/blob/master/src/com/pygame_studio/settings/appearance_and_behavior/AppearanceAndBehavior.java

The sub-sub-class that the Settings object uses:

https://github.com/Eno-Gerguri/Pygame-Studio/blob/master/src/com/pygame_studio/settings/appearance_and_behavior/Font.java

When I try to deserialise the object in a separate file:

```
private Settings defaultSettings = settingsManager.deserializeSettings(DefaultSettings.DEFAULT_SETTINGS_FILE_DIRECTORY);
```

The following error log

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: N/A
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 356] (through reference chain: com.pygame_studio.settings.Settings["appearanceAndBehavior"]->com.pygame_studio.settings.appearance_and_behavior.AppearanceAndBehavior["font"]->com.pygame_studio.settings.appearance_and_behavior.Font["fontDirectory"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:278)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty._throwAsIOE(SettableBeanProperty.java:611)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty._throwAsIOE(SettableBeanProperty.java:599)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:143)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:288)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:288)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:288)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4202)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3205)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3173)
    at com.pygame_studio.settings.SettingsManager.deserializeSettings(SettingsManager.java:75)
    at com.pygame_studio.start_menu.StartMenu.<init>(StartMenu.java:24)
    at com.pygame_studio.PygameStudio.<init>(PygameStudio.java:18)
    at com.pygame_studio.PygameStudio.main(PygameStudio.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.pygame_studio.settings.appearance_and_behavior.Font.setFontDirectory(Font.java:115)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:141)
    ... 15 more
```

I know that in the function:
com.pygame_studio.settings.appearance_and_behavior.Font.setFontDirectory

```
public void setFontDirectory(String fontDirectory) {
        if (externalFonts.containsKey(fontDirectory)) {
            this.fontDirectory = externalFonts.get(fontDirectory);
        } else if (localFonts.contains(fontDirectory)) {
            this.fontDirectory = fontDirectory;
        } else {
            this.fontDirectory = this.getFallbackFont();
        }
    }
```

externalFonts Hashtable is null because it has not been initialised however, it should be as in the constructer:

```
    public Font() {
        super();
    }
    
    public Font(File externalFontDirectory, String fontName, int fontStyle, int fontSize, String fallbackFont) {
        this.setExternalFontDirectory(externalFontDirectory);
        
        this.setExternalFonts();  // External fonts is set before the font directory.
        this.setLocalFonts();
        
        this.setFontDirectory(fontName);  // Font directory being set after externalFonts.
        
        this.setFontStyle(fontStyle);
        
        this.setFontSize(fontSize);
        
        this.setFallbackFont(fallbackFont);
    }
```

setExternalFonts method:

```
    public void setExternalFonts() {
        externalFonts = getExternalFonts(this.externalFontDirectory);
    }
```

getExternalFonts method:

```
    public static Hashtable<String, String> getExternalFonts(File externalFontDirectory) {
        Hashtable<String, String> externalFonts = new Hashtable<>();
        
        final File[] directoryFiles = externalFontDirectory.listFiles();
        
        if (directoryFiles != null) {
            for (File file : directoryFiles) {
                if (file.isDirectory()) {  // If the file is a sub-directory.
                    externalFonts.putAll(getExternalFonts(file));  // Calls itself onto the directory.
                } else if (file.getName().contains(".ttf")) {  // If the file is a font.
                    String fontName = file.getName().replace(".ttf", "");  // Gets the name of the font.
                    externalFonts.put(fontName, file.getPath());  // Puts the, name of the font : font's directory, into the Hashtable.
                }
            }
        }
        return externalFonts;
    }
```

However, my IDE Eclipse tells me that this code is never reached, when it should be to initialise externalFonts.

Why is this method not being called?
How do I fix this issue so I can successfully deserialise the xml into a "Settings" object?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Static fields are not serialized or deserialized.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne My .xml file created, stores all of the values of externalFonts and localFonts, so I am not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific problem is here in the `Font` class:

```
public static Hashtable<String, String> externalFonts;
```

First I would recommend changing this from `Hashtable` to `HashMap` - these days there is no reason (in my experience) to use `Hashtable` over any of the more modern collection classes. You can read community opinions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/differences-between-hashmap-and-hashtable).

Second, the field needs to be initialized, so it is not null - like you do for the `localFonts` list.

So that gives us this:

```
public static Map<String, String> externalFonts = new HashMap();
```

You will then need to replace the remaining references to `Hashtable`, of course.

When I made that change, it fixed the specific problem you reported.

Comment: Would I replace all references to `Hashtable` with `Map` or `HashMap`? I assume `Map`.

Comment: Typically, the interface (`Map`) is what you pass around: `public Map<String, String> getExternalFonts()`. And use the implementation (`HashMap`) in assignments: `Map<String, String> externalFonts = new HashMap<>();`. Does that make sense?

Comment: You can read more about the difference and usage [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348199/what-is-the-difference-between-the-hashmap-and-map-objects-in-java). And apologies if I'm telling you things you already know.